# How can I detect when an iframe page begins loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'd like for the opener of an iframe to be able to detect each time the user changes pages within that iframe.  Using jQuery, I can detect each time a page *finishes* loading within an iframe via the following:

```
$('#myIframe').on('load', function() {/*do stuff*/});
```

However, I'd also like to detect (in the iframe *opener*) each time a page *starts* loading within that iframe.

Note: The content that is displayed in the iframe is from a third-party site, so I don't have the ability to insert code there so that the iframe can explicitly alert the opener.

Does anyone know of an event that is fired when a page begins loading? I'm not having much luck finding anything via Internet searches, as most people seem to only be interested in detecting when the iframe has *finished* loading.

Comment: How are u loading the content on the iframe, is it through javascript when parent window gets loaded completely or just on the same http reponse of the parent window ?? Based on that I think I could answer your question??

Comment: 3rd party [aka another domain]? Same Origin Policy

Comment: I the parent window, I'm dynamically creating an iframe tag (based on a trigger from the user), the 'src' property of which is set to an external, third-party site.

Comment: You are having ::: the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem

Comment: Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: @Troy  Read my edited answer.....that might help

Comment: Thanks. I am familiar with the same-origin policy. However, the "load" event works despite the iframe content being from a different domain, so it seemed reasonable that a similar event might exist for when the page *begins* loading. Apparently, and unfortunately, no such event exists...

Answer (score 1):

It seems unfortunately that the only way to be sure it will work in most browsers is to use the `<iframe onload="myonloadscript();"`

The `window.onload` event of the main page will tell you when the iframe has loaded and you can be sure it has begun it's request for it's src page

---

**Edit:**

Just copying it from an article ([Their are hacks for this](http://blog.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/))

*doing this cross-domain? Not so easy. You’ll get something along the line of: Child document does not have the right to access parent document. In fact there is a lot of documentation on the web about how to achieve it, but the problem is that it is often outdated, with solutions that often only works in a couples of browsers.*

Comment: I had tested the onload property of the iframe, but that also appears to wait until the page has finished loading (same as the jQuery example in my original question).